# How to put the icon to the left of action bar tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using the ActionBar.Tab, and they always appear at the left of screen. I want to put the activity icon to the left of tabs, but it always appear at the right of tabs. How can I move their position to where I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what works for me like a dream:
in the Activity I have this:

```
    //hiding default app icon
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    //displaying custom ActionBar
    View mActionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_action_bar, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(mActionBarView);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)
```

my_action_bar.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/turquoise">

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/btn_slide"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_slide"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

//use your custom xml view to show your icon at left

```
View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_custom_view, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Comment: I did that, but the custom view will appear between tabs and action bar icons. How do I position the custom view to the left of tabs instead of between tabs and action bar icons?

Answer (score -1):

on your `onCreate()` method if you are on the activity

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
.setIcon(<the icon you want>)
.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
.setTabListener(this));
```