# How to create ActionBar With Button Items Using Android?

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar

I need to create `ActionBar` with left side button item looks like below mentioned Image. I tried by using huge of codes, but still I didnt get anything. Please help me to create android `ActionBar` with button.

I need to create like below 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEx3I.png)

**NOTE:** I don't have sample code, Moreover It's not proper because I am new developer for android.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this ?http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Comment: No...That I can do bcz I have samples.. I need to create Actionbar with lefthand side menu button and small gap to mention activity title. Below thats titles with button for listview header!

Comment: Then add navigation drawer with the action bar, You can find the code here http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/. and here http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android

Comment: I need basic step by step process. Sorry because I am a new developer for Android!

Comment: These are basic step by step processes, you can try by simply copy paste the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Add Action Buttons add this in your activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

 //and this to handle actions


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

and this in your main.xml under menu directory

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" 
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:orderInCategory="100" 
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

***To get the icon to the left see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815352/how-to-put-the-icon-to-the-left-of-action-bar-tabs)***

Comment: First of all thank you for helping me...How to add button on leftside action bar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815352/how-to-put-the-icon-to-the-left-of-action-bar-tabs

Comment: Awesome @Mrad Mrad. Thank you buddy!