# I found difficulty to display icon for ActionBar in Android VS 1.5 with SDK 21.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-styles

Below is the code and I could not found solutions for displaying icon.I found difficulty to display icon for ActionBar in Android VS 1.5 with SDK 21.0. 
Below is the code and I could not found solutions for displaying icon.

### style.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="icon">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.saisunsolutions.ifinco">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".splaseActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

### splashActivity.java

```
package com.saisunsolutions.ifinco;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan;

public class splaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splase);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create android resource directory with menu name then inside menu create action_bar.xml like this

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="test"/>
```

then in your activity override onCreateOptionMenu like below

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: It's work but icon is displaying right side of the ActionBar. I need to get it on left side.

Comment: you can use this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815352/how-to-put-the-icon-to-the-left-of-action-bar-tabs)